# facebook like button to like page and image on this page

Tags: facebook-like

I have website display images, each image has its facebook-like button linked to its facebook url.
What I want is, when the user click like image the like action do like for my page first and then the like of the image. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you will need two separate like buttons, one for your page and one for the image.